# Custom Font provided by Application does not work

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, fonts, info.plist

I just uploaded a new group folder called Font which inside contains the .ttf font file. in the .plist file I just added the  Font provided by Application key and in the string the name of the file correctly... I did check with :

```
for family: AnyObject in UIFont.familyNames() {
println("Font Family: \(family)")
for font: AnyObject in UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName(family as NSString) {
    println("Font Name: \(font)")
} }
```

Anyhow still not showing me in the text custom font properties the new Font.

[The folder and font fil + Info.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiwGF.png)

[Copy Bundle ressources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gg73E.png)

Comment: did you install ttf file ?

Comment: install? I did copy the file into my project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have just same error to custom fonts and when i try firstly I did not choose the **Copy  Items** and **Add to Target** option . Then fonts did not work in my application .

I choose the all `.otf` and `.ttf` files and removed from the project and I tried again with copying and targetting items in project . Then it worked for me .

[image]

I hope this helps for your problem

Comment: I did the same, just removed the ttf file, did all the process again and it works fine....well just strange it did not work in the first try

Comment: First time when i trying the different fonts , it did not work for me , so i realized the problem in other topics about this situation with importance of copying files into project . its nice to work for your project :)

Comment: I forgot to tick **Add to targets**